# Adding a time.sleep() method for Google Translate API in python

Tags: python, django, sleep, google-translate

I'm setting up a `Django` Views that requests products data from an API, parse them with `BeautifulSoup`, apply the `googletrans` module and save the response into my Postgresql database. I have a `429` HTTP error when I run my script because I send to many requests at once and I was adviced to add a `time.sleep()` method of 2 seconds to fix the issue.

The only thing is that I'm not sure where should I place this method in my script, and I need to make sure that its the right way to do it before risking of getting my IP address blocked by `Google tranlsate API` again.

This is my Views:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googletrans import Translator
import requests
import json


def api_data(request):
    if request.GET.get('mybtn'):  # to improve, == 'something':
        resp_1 = requests.get(
            "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?language=fr&cityCode=PARIS&limit=5000&currencyCode=CAD",
            headers={
                "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
            })
        resp_1_data = resp_1.json()
        base_url_2 = "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/get/"

        translator = Translator()

        for item in resp_1_data['items']:
            print('translating item {}'.format(item['id']))
            # concat ID to the URL string
            url = '{}{}'.format(base_url_2, item['id'] + '?language=fr')

            # make the HTTP request
            resp_2 = requests.get(
                url,
                headers={
                    "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
                })
            resp_2_data = resp_2.json()

            descriptiontxt = resp_2_data['contentListHtml'][0]['html'][0:2040] + ' ...'

            #Parsing work
            soup = BeautifulSoup(descriptiontxt, 'lxml')
            parsed = soup.find('p').text

            #Translation doesn't work
            translation = translator.translate(parsed, dest='fr')

            titlename = item['name']
            titlefr = translator.translate(titlename, dest='fr')

            destinationname = item['city']['name']
            destinationfr = translator.translate(destinationname, dest='fr')

            Product.objects.get_or_create(
                title=titlefr.text,
                destination=destinationfr.text,
                description=translation.text,
                link=item['canonicalUrl'],
                image=item['image']['url']
            )

    return render(request, "form.html")
```

This is what I came out with, is this okay?

```
  Product.objects.get_or_create(
      title=titlefr.text,
      destination=destinationfr.text,
      description=translation.text,
      link=item['canonicalUrl'],
      image=item['image']['url']
  )time.sleep(2) #here
```

or like this:

```
resp_1 = requests.get(
            "https://www.headout.com/api/public/v1/product/listing/list-by/city?language=fr&cityCode=PARIS&limit=5000&currencyCode=CAD",
            headers={
                "Headout-Auth": HEADOUT_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
            }, time.sleep(2)) #or here
```

Please help.

**EDIT**

Based on @jay answer, Is this correct?

```
  Product.objects.get_or_create(
      title=titlefr.text,
      destination=destinationfr.text,
      description=translation.text,
      link=item['canonicalUrl'],
      image=item['image']['url']
  )

  #at the very end of the for loop
  time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: What's problem ? Show us error.

Comment: why on Earth would you need or want a scraper to get data from an API call? I just checked the URL, it returns JSON data as I expected. Things like BS are only used for getting data from HTML pages, and it's an inherently messy process - there's absolutely no need if the site gives you a nice API to use to access the data directly.

Comment: I'm trying to know where I should place the time.sleep() method in my code above. Because originally, when I run this code, I get a 429 error and Google translate is blocking my IP address for too many requests.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I agree with what your saying, but we need to control our data since we have a machine learning model that Is applied manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend at the very end of the for loop, so that it waits 2 seconds before relooping.

```py
        destinationname = item['city']['name']
        destinationfr = translator.translate(destinationname, dest='fr')

        Product.objects.get_or_create(
            title=titlefr.text,
            destination=destinationfr.text,
            description=translation.text,
            link=item['canonicalUrl'],
            image=item['image']['url']
        )
        time.sleep(2)

return render(request, "form.html")
```

Comment: Working! Do you think 1 sec would be good, because doing 2sec is pretty long for 1000 items...

Comment: I don't know. I'm unfamiliar with google's bot blockers. Honestly, I would  -- from random import randint -- and then use time.sleep(randint(1, 3)), if you want to appear slick

Comment: Great, and what does this do? Is this changing the time from 1 to 3 sec randomly for each loop?

Comment: Cool, I think I will stay with the 2sec for now just to make sure that I don't get blocked again